# Anonymous editable link doesn't allow edit an excel file

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to create an editable anonymous link for an Excel file from SharePoint document library. As per the documentation Microsoft Graph C# SDK, I should be able to use createLink API with this code.

```
var driveItem = await graphClient.Drive
                    .Items[itemId]
                    .CreateLink("edit", "anonymous", null, null, null)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync();

return driveItem.Link.WebUrl;
```

But with the created link I can only view the excel file. The link does not allow editing the excel file. How can I create the link for the excel file?

Also, the same code working with MS Word files.

I am using Share Point Document Library and calling the APIs via Microsoft graph explorer.

Comment: When you call createLink via Graph Explorer what do you receive in response? ("roles": [
        "?" ], "link": { "preventsDownload": ?, "scope": "?", "type": "?"}

Comment: If you have that excel document in sharepoint document library you should give the siteid,driveid and then itemid in you code, something like this `graphClient.Sites["siteid"].Drives["driveid"]
                    .Items[itemId]
                    .CreateLink("edit", "anonymous", null, null, null)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync();` This worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that excel document in sharepoint document library you should give the siteid,driveid and then itemid in you code, something like this.

```
graphClient.Sites["siteid"]
    .Drives["documentlibraryid"]
    .Items["itemId"]                     
    .CreateLink("edit", "anonymous", null, null, null)
    .Request()                     
    .PostAsync();
```

This way I was able to edit the excel file without logging as anonymous. I had also tested it in POSTMAN which also worked perfectly.

[image]